# DOSBOX0.74 Overlay with number indicator

Tags: windows, dosbox

When I start dosbox a number appear as an overlay. I can't get ride of this overlay. I even installed all again. 
Tried also all short cuts what was given on the page, but this 'overlay'  appear in every instance of Dosbox I  and stays there, no matter what I do.

Anyone an Idea what this number indicate  and how to get ride of it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: DOSBox isn't a primarily programming related tool, so your question is off-topic here. You might want to check that you don't have something like FRAPS installed on your machine, and that's what's displaying the numbers.

Comment: That does look a lot like fraps to me.

Comment: Thank for this answer. I don't have FRAPS, others pointed me on Geforce Experience. What can cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found. It was caused by the Geforce ShadowPlay
Although this wasn't even active (I just looked at it once then shut it off) It still made itself active in some background process, giving extra information in an overlay on certain programs and apps